# Insert user defined string into formula

Tags: excel, vba

I duplicate a report and rename the tab as per user input.

I need to take that user input and insert it into a formula which would then be placed into a cell. Over time (monthly) the formula would need to change columns.

Below is what I have done so far.

`sName` is the user defined input, I think I have declared it as a global variable correctly

`sName` is used in `SPVCLookup` as the name of the tab (not working)

`sName` is used in `countif` as part of a formula (not working)

```
' will copy SPC Report to new tab and ask user to name the tab

Dim sName As String

Sub CopyRename()
    'Dim sName As String
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Worksheets("SPC Report").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Set wks = ActiveSheet
    Do While sName <> wks.Name
        sName = Application.InputBox _
          (Prompt:="Enter new worksheet name")
        On Error Resume Next
        wks.Name = sName
        On Error GoTo 0
    Loop
    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub

'------------------------
Sub CreateDA()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ws = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = "Departmental Analysis"
    End With
End Sub
'------------------------
Sub SPCVlookup() 
    'Sheets("sName").Select 'this needs to be user defined 
    Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,'Card Exchange'!$A$1:$V$218,6,FALSE)"
End Sub

Sub Countif()
    Sheets("Departmental Analysis").Select

    ' I think I need a for loop to cycle through the range columns
     Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('sname'!$A$1:$E$12104,A3)"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got two problems here.

---

```
Sub SPCVlookup() 
    Sheets("sName").Select 'selects the sheet called "sName"
    Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,'Card Exchange'!$A$1:$V$218,6,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

This code selects the sheet called `"sName"`. Remove the `""` marks:

```
Sub SPCVlookup() 
    Sheets("sName").Select 'selects the sheet called "sName"
    Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(D2,'Card Exchange'!$A$1:$V$218,6,FALSE)"
End Sub
```

---

```
Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('sname'!$A$1:$E$12104,A3)"
```

This is a bit trickier. You'll need to copy `sName` into the formula, but in order to do so you'll need to escape it (just in case `sName` contains quotes). You can do that by doubling each quote:

```
Replace(sName, """", """"&"""")
```

So...

```
Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown)).Formula = "=COUNTIFS('" & Replace(sName, """", """"&"""") & "'!$A$1:$E$12104,A3)"
```

This won't update the cells when `sName` changes; to do that, you'll need to set a spreadsheet name. Variables in VBA and Formulas aren't shared.

Comment: Hi wizzwizz4, Thanks for your reply, I have tried to replace the errors you said i have but with no joy. I think i havent declared the string sName correctly or that its not holding the value for use later in the module. Should it be dim sName or Public sName as string.

Comment: update- so this does work however everything needs to be under Sub CopyRename (). Thanks for that but i need it to be in separate sub and still work as the user will need to activate different macro buttons at different times. This is just a snippet of a larger code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @user10523535 It looks like `xlDown` isn't defined, which could stop it working properly. I don't really know, though.